# how to save only the modified data from datagridview in c#

Tags: c#

i have a problem i create an editable datagridview 
in which in each row there is a 'update' button
when i make a change in a row and press the 'update' button then it save only the modified data and reject all data

fox example if a customer return something from his invoice so only that rows will save in return table in which we create some modification and reject the others

so basically i have two problem;
1) how to detect the changes in a datagrid
2) and then save only the modified rows!

this is my code for getting the invoice in datagrid
           private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

```
        string query = @"Select Item.ItemName as item, Stock.SalePrice as 
        Price, invoice.Qty 
        FROM invoice
        JOIN item ON invoice.ItemID = item.ItemID
        JOIN sale ON invoice.SaleID = sale.SaleID
        join Stock on Stock.ItemID  = item.ItemID 
        where sale.SaleID = '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SDA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


        DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn);
        btn.HeaderText = "Update";
        btn.Text = "Update";
        btn.Name = "btnUpdate";
        btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

    }
```

but when i make edit in the quantity and press the update button it save all the datagidview data which i don't

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
     DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
            {

            String Query = @"INSERT INTO b_bsale(b_bsale.item_id, 
            b_bsale.sale_price, b_bsale.qty) VALUES ('" + 1 + "','" + 33 + 
            "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value + "')";
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, con);
            con.Open();
            SDA.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Data Entered!", "Congragulation!", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

            }
```

i want to save only edited data and reject all the unedited data

Comment: are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem you have? Please see [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: no i m using dot.net framework

Comment: simple i have data in a datagridview and i want to save it in database row by row only thats rows in which changes occur

Comment: @Mrkhan And what is the problem in doing so? What is the source code you have? How do you react on changes in the datagridview in your source code? What is the error/exception you get?

Comment: please my code and help me thanks

Comment: The `DataGridView` has a [dozen events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.7.2#events) which you can subscribe to. For example [CellValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) can be used to be informed when a value was changed. Then you could write the row index into a list to know which rows have been changed.

Comment: @Oliver can you please mention the code here.. i already used the cellValueChanged event but don't make a list.. coz i don't know how to make a list of edited row.. its will be your greatness please mention the code

Comment: You don't need to iterate over al values in a for-loop. Instead use the given event arguments: `var changedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];` Then you can update only that entry within the database.

Comment: Nevertheless your code lacks so much other things. Like using a real class with properties for the values and not hard-coded column indices (hint: BindingSource). Also your update statement is open for sql injection (hint: SqlParameter). Also you hardcoded the item id and the sale price into the statement instead of taking it from the given row. And doing all this stuff directly within the event just hurts my eyes. No abstractions or anything else. You gotta lot to learn.